# can't find ipaddress of my raspberrypi

Tags: boot

i typed `sudo ip addr show` but can't see raspberrypi address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:45:c4:a2:4a:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::7a45:c4ff:fea2:4a63/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:4b:f5:30:ba:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Do you have a monitor hooked up? Or are you plugging into your network?

Comment: You may like to try `sudo ifconfig -a`...?

Comment: You can't find the `inet` address because you don't have one. You need to provide more detail about your network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing in ifconfig and your IP should be displayed next to inet addr:

Comment: Append a grep to hone in directly to the ip such as `ifconfig | grep 192.168`

Answer (score 0):

You can be a little more specific in your question towards `ip` and say

```
ip show eth0
```

if it is the ethernet ip address you are interested in.

It seems to me that you are using ipv6 internally (well done!) so on the line starting with inet6, your ip address is listed.

Comment: I think you will find the `inet6` is a link local address.